# opengl : texture deletion

Tags: winapi, opengl

I am working on an OpenGL renderer in Win32... I was wondering, when a texture is bound to an ID if it is automatically destroyed and wiped from the video memory when the rendering context is destroyed, or does that count as a memory leak if they are left bound when the process terminates suddenly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All OpenGL resources are per-process, so it is reasonable to assume they get cleaned up on termination. Otherwise, you'd get nasty system-wide memory leaks on crashing applications - something completely unacceptable on any half-decent OS.

Comment: Not that Windows counts as half-decent ;-).